# PHP round up list items to nearest five

Tags: php, list, rounding

I've got a grid of 10 square list items. A bit like a gallery. If the user adds another item there will be 11. However this will look strange as the 11<sup>th</sup> item will be on its own in a new row. How can I use PHP to round up to the nearest 5 and add in the some blank/dummy list items?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: In your specific use case, I'd output the list items and not worry out presentation. Then in your CSS, work out how to best present it using either a fluid page design (in which you probably wouldn't care about the 5 columns) or a predefined page width (in which case you can set the width of your list item to pagewidth/5).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to identify the remainder of a division:

```
10 % 5 = 0
11 % 5 = 1
12 % 5 = 2
13 % 5 = 3
14 % 5 = 4
15 % 5 = 0
```

With that you can identify if (and how large) such an uncomplete row would be. Knowing how many elements are in that last uncomplete row oviously allows you to calculate the number of remaining cells to fill the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
($y+(($y%$x)?($x-($y%$x)):0))
```

...where **$y** is the number of items(e.g. 11) and **$x** is the number of items in a row(e.g. 5)